# Hola a todos quiero hacer que cuando tipeen 15 se repita 15 veces si es 10 se repita 10 veces la imagen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, funciones

['../wp-content/plugins/Wordpress_CRUD_Plugin-master/img/PMb.png', '../wp-content/plugins/Wordpress_CRUD_Plugin-master/img/planopisovariadob.png'],
                ];
        foreach ($pisosmedios as $piso) {
            ?>

```
        <tr class="PisosMedios"></tr>
        <td><span class="txtpiso">Piso <?php echo $i-- ?></span>
            <img class="imgpisos" src="<?php echo $piso[0] ?>"  onmouseover="peligro('<?php echo $piso[1] ?>')"></td>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta no se entiende. Si tienes un problema el primer paso es saber explicar ese problema. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano mi problema consiste en que quiero repetir la imagen n veces donde n sea el valor ingresado por medio de una caja de text tipe number sin enviar a ningun lugar solo imprimirlo en la misma pagina

Comment: Ya, pero ese no es el problema, eso es lo que quieres hacer, que también está bien que lo expliques. Pero el problema o error ¿cuál es? ¿El código cuál es? ¿Qué muestra ahora? Yo veo un trozo de código donde se construyen filas de una tabla, pero, ¿dónde está la otra parte y cómo imprimes el todo?

Comment: @A.Cedano <script>
    $("input").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();
</script> con este tomo el valor de mi campo pero no se hacer que me lo repita me recomendaron que mejor lo hiciera con ajax pero soy nuevo en esto es para mi clase de programacion

Comment: Aquí se te puede ayudar en cualquier ámbito, pero es preciso que se entienda el problema. Nosotros no estamos en tu mente ni frente a tu pantalla para saber lo que tienes y lo que quieres hacer, por tanto debes explicarlo tú, redactando una pregunta en la que se entienda el problema, se vean los mensajes de error si los hay y un mínimo de código verificable. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta. Si tienes que perder media hora redactando bien la pregunta, pierde media hora, que no es perder, es ganar. Si no, podemos pasar horas y días aquí preguntándote cosas para tratar de entender.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones, pero yo te voy a poner dos, tu solamente tendrías que estudiar el código y entender dónde hacer los cambios pertinentes:

**CON PROMPT**

```js
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{//Esperamos a que la pagina se cargue
    let num = prompt('Elige un numero');//Hacemos que elija un numero por le prompt
        while(!num || isNaN(num)){//Siempre y cuando no haya, o no sea un numero,
            num = prompt('Elige un numero');//el prompt entrara en bucle
        }

    let rpt = document.querySelector('.repeat');//Defino lo que quiero que se repita
                                                //en este caso, el valor de la etiqueta

    if(num <= 100){//para no hacer demasiadas iteraciones, le puse un tope, 100
    //si el numero metido por el prompt es menor que 100 hara el bucle for
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){//inicializamos el bucle for, poniendo como valor de salida el numero
        console.log(rpt.innerHTML);//metido por el prompt. Sumamos +1 a 'i' hasta completar el bucle
        }
    } else {//si num es mayor que 100, entonces no va a imprimir nada, pero es suprimible
        console.log('El numero es muy grande');
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>039 : menu de teclado</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/039.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/039.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="controller">

    <p class="repeat" style="display: none;">Etiqueta de repeticion</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CON INPUT**

```js
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{//cargamos pagina
    let inp = document.querySelector('input');//definimos el input

    inp.addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>{//hacemos un evento de escucha en el input, y pasamos los valores como parametro 'e'
        if(e.key == 'Enter'){//si el parametro 'e' coincide con la tecla 'Enter', entonces ejecutara el siguiente codigo
            let res = inp.value;                //tambien se podria haber hecho mas facil con un boton, pero no quieres botones
            if(!res || isNaN(res)){//hacemos la misma verificacion en el valor del input que con el prompt, solo que aqui no entramos en un bucle per se
                alert('inserta un número valido');//nos salta una alarma hasta que lo hagamos bien
                inp.value = '';//y te borra el contenido del input
            } else {
                goToNextFunction(parseInt(res));//sino ira a la siguiente funcion, no sabia como llamarla, y pasamos el valor res como parseInt()
            }       //ya que res es una cadena de texto, y necesitamos su valor numerico
        }
    });
});


function goToNextFunction(r){//aqui recogemos el valor numerico de res como parametro
    console.log(r);//lo puedes ver aqui, que saldra el numero en verde, si fuera texto, saldria negro
    let rpt = document.getElementsByClassName('repeat')[0];//uso otro metodo de seleccion, uno que carga menos la pagina
                    //al definir que tipo de busqueda es, si fuera con querySelector, no se definiria, y tendria que definirse sobre la marcha
    if(r <= 100){//mismo criterio de iteracion
        for(i=0;i<r;i++){//bucle blablabla
            console.log(rpt.innerHTML);//sacamos el resultado por consola
        }
    } else {
        console.log('El numero es muy grande, pon algo menor a 100');//y sino te quedas a dos velas
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>039 : menu de teclado</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/039.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/039.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="controller">

    <p class="repeat" style="display: none;">Etiqueta de repeticion</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**MOSTRAR POR PANTALLA**

De la anterior solución, cambia la última función si quieres que el resultado se muestre por pantalla en vez de por consola:

```
function goToNextFunction(r){//otra funcion distinta, en la que mostramos por pantalla el resultado, no por consola
    let rpt = document.querySelector('.repeat');//cogemos lo que queremos repetir

    if(r < 100){//hacemos el selector
        for(i=0;i<r;i++){//iniciamos bucle
            let dv = document.createElement('div');//creamos elemento div con cada iteracion
                dv.innerHTML = rpt.innerHTML;//agregamos el contenido del rpt al contenido del div creado con cada iteracion
            document.body.appendChild(dv);//hacemos hijo del body al div con cada iteracion
        }
    } else {//sino, nada
        console.log('no');
    }
}
```